# Accents in MongoDB not displaying or stored properly

Tags: mongodb, diacritics, case-insensitive

I have imported documents with fields that contain accents using `mongoImport`:

```
D:\Apps\Mongo\Install\bin>mongoimport --db test --collection test --file MongoExport.json.
```

My file is in `UTF-8` and the accents look good.  Once in `Mongo` they are all messed up.

Is there any setting in `Mongo` to support accents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Converted The File To UTF Without BOM And re Imported the JSON and it Worked Fine.